# How to strictly justify text in bootstrap 5

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

I want to strictly justify text as shown below. This picture is taken from Libre Office.

**Libra Office:**
[image]

**Webpage looks like this:**
[image]

How can I make the webpage look like the way it is formatted in Libre Office?

**I'm using Bootstrap 5**:

```css
.about {
  text-align: right;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BmbxuPwQa2lc/FVzBcNJ7UAyJxM6wuqIj61tLrc4wSX0szH/Ev+nYRRuWlolflfl" crossorigin="anonymous" />
</head>
<div class="container" data-aos="fade-up">
  <div class="about text-justify">
    <header class="section-header">
      <h3>About Nadi Astrology</h3>
      <p>
        These days we hear about people with powers of extra sensory perceptions. (ESP). The Rishies were Holy Sages who occupied themselves in concentrating on the one Divine Being Paramathma. They far exceeded the powers of the E.S.P. People. More than that
        are able to know the future by their foresight. With this foresight, Rishies like Kousiha, Agasthiya, Vashishta, Mahasiva Vakkiyar have given predictions for the human being occupying this world. Let us take for instance any particular moment
        of a day. Many lives are born in the world at at any given moment. Human lives, plant life and animals. The Rishies have ignored the last to and confines their predictions only to human our of their wisdom envisaged will come forward to study
        these predictions. The exact age in which watch such person will come for the study has also been foretold by the Rishies.
      </p>
      <p></p>
    </header>
  </div>
</div>

</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works in Bootstrap 5. Found the solution [here](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/34993).

```html
<p  style="text-align: justify;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
```

Comment: not like it has anything to do with bootstrap at all. This is simply a css. While it works.

Answer (score 13):

as simple as that:

```css
.about p {
  margin: 0;
  text-indent: 2rem;
  text-align: justify;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container" data-aos="fade-up">
  <div class="about text-justify">
    <header class="section-header">
      <p>These days we hear about people with powers of extra sensory perceptions.  (ESP).  The Rishies were Holy Sages who occupied themselves in concentrating on the one Divine Being Paramathma.  They far exceeded the powers of the E.S.P. People.  More than that are able to know the future by their foresight.  With this foresight, Rishies like Kousiha, Agasthiya, Vashishta, Mahasiva Vakkiyar have given predictions for the human being occupying this world.  Let us take for instance any particular moment of a day.  Many lives are born in the world at at any given moment.  Human lives, plant life and animals.  The Rishies have ignored the last to and confines their predictions only to human our of their wisdom envisaged will come forward to study these predictions. The exact age in which watch such person will come for the study has also been foretold by the Rishies.</p>
      <p>These days we hear about people with powers of extra sensory perceptions.  (ESP).  The Rishies were Holy Sages who occupied themselves in concentrating on the one Divine Being Paramathma.  They far exceeded the powers of the E.S.P. People.</p>
    </header>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `class="text-justify"` the code i actually looking for

Comment: in bootstrap 5.0 this has been deprecated

Answer (score 3):

You can do this by adding it to your CSS / Bootstrap CSS file:

```
.text-justify{text-align:justify !important;}
```

HTML:

```
<p class="text-justify">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</p>
```

Answer (score 2):

Bootstrap don't support justified text. As they mentioned:

> Note that we don’t provide utility classes for justified text. While, aesthetically, justified text might look more appealing, it does make word-spacing more random and therefore harder to read.

So, you should define justified text by your own.
Inline:

```html
<p  style="text-align: justify;">Lorem ipsum</p>
```

or by CSS class:

```css
.justify{
  text-align: justify;
  }
```

```html
<p  class="justify">Lorem ipsum</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it adding code:

```
.about { text-align: justify; text-justify: inter-word; }
```

Comment: @Raphel it didnt work . here is what i get... https://i.ibb.co/MkgQYjH/Screenshot-from-2021-02-15-00-41-52.png  i tried as you said.

Comment: it looks like some style has been inherited and centres up your text

Comment: i tried important but it didnt work .can you suggest some quick fix.

Comment: yes, tried this as well again - pls remove style: text-justify: inter-word;

Comment: .about { text-align: justify!important;} tried this one but didnt work

Comment: looks like your style is being overridden by some additional style

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228707/discussion-between-raphael-and-soman-raj).

Comment: Thank you so much for trying to help me.... But the answer from Sergey Sklyar worked fine...Thanks for your kind heartiness and willingness to help.Thank you so much

Comment: this is what have written: text-align: justify;

Comment: margin: 0;
 text-indent: 2rem;   Ya Raphael but this 2 lines made it work

Comment: those styles have nothing to do with the text justification...

Comment: @ya Raphael ...But i was new to css ... and i tried as you said .but couldnt get the desired output due to my lack of knowledge in css . any way thank you so much Raphael for your support ..

Comment: Good you achieved your goal. Good luck